# Accessing a BOOL flag set in several different possible classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, boolean

I have two values whose relationship to each other will be displayed in my primary view controller in two different ways, depending upon the reason (the place in the code) the values are set. My attempts to this point have become convoluted and the results ambiguous due to calculating the values individually in their far-flung classes.

So I've decided to set a Boolean flag indicating the display mode to be checked and acted upon accordingly in `viewWillAppear` of the primary VC.

My question:

How to set such a Boolean? Should it be a property of the primary View Controller, then create an instance of that VC at each point where the numbers are changed?

Thanks! All help appreciated!

Comment: You might consider using `NSNotificationCenter` to broadcast the change whenever it changes.  Then your various View Controllers can just subscribe to the appropriate notification.  Where you actually store it could be in your `UIApplicationDelegate`, `NSUserPreferences` or some other singleton, depending on the structure of your code...

Comment: if my answer helped you please mark it as accepted

Comment: Please see my answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok--

First, many thanks to those who read and particularly those who responded. The information and examples are illuminating.

As it turns out, at least in this particular case, the answer was to pass the flag back through delegation, which I was already using in 3 of the five cases in question. I just modified the delegate scheme to include the other two cases, and everything fell into place.

Apologies for the long response time--I had to step away on an unrelated mater.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I usually create a singleton class that gets loaded when the app starts for example AppSharedData for such situations whenever i face a situation that i have to use a variable that is set or manipulated in different classes i set it as a public property of the AppShareData here is a small example :

AppSharedData.h :

```
@interface AppSharedData : NSObject
+(AppSharedData*)sharedInstance ;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL sharedBoolVariable ;
@end
```

AppSharedData.m :

```
@implementation AppSharedData
@synthesize sharedBoolVariable;
+(AppSharedData *) sharedInstance
{
   static AppSharedData *_sharedInstance = nil;
   static dispatch_once_t Token;
   dispatch_once(&Token, ^{
      _sharedInstance = [[AppSharedData alloc]init];
   });
   return _sharedInstance;
}
@end
```

and then if you want to edit the value of the variable in any class i would do the following :

```
-(void)editMethod
{
   AppSharedData * dataObject = [AppSharedData sharedInstance] ; 
   dataObject = YES ; 
}
```

and if i want to retrieve the value of the variable in any class i do the following :

```
-(void)retrieveMethod
{
   AppSharedData * dataObject = [AppSharedData sharedInstance] ; 
   BOOL someVariableInMyClass = [dataObject sharedBoolVariable] ; 
}
```

and of course the AppShareData is a singleton class so it is only created once in the lifetime of the app so :

1. you don't have to worry about over memory allocation .
2. this guarantee that the variables are shared (ie if you edit a variable in one class and then retrieve its value in another class it will be the new value ) .

Comment: This general idea is called "model-view-controller" and is a key design pattern in Cocoa. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html In this case, `AppSharedData` is the model. It doesn't have to be a singleton; you could also construct one during program startup and pass it to the view controllers, but it's not uncommon to use a singleton for this.

Comment: @RobNapier yes i know about MVC , if you want to put in a MVC context this would be considered the APP model  , but i my opinion is MVC is not a stand alone design pattern , you have to use others to make it work smoothly , just like the singleton pattern , but that just my opinion of course , i am happy to chat with you about MVC or any other patter at anytime .